# HTML5 Browser history - как поменять содержимое страницы?

Tags: javascript, html5, html5-history-api, history-api

Начал учить HTML5 Browser history и задался вопросом:

> Если я могу поменять URL в браузере, то как можно менять содержимое?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>History browser API</title>
</head>
<body>
  <a onclick="nextPage();"><h2>Next page</h2></a>
  <a onclick="back();"><h2>Back</h2></a>
  <script type="application/javascript">
    function nextPage() {
      history.pushState ("bar.html", "Страница #2", "/bar.html");
    }
    function back() {
      history.back();
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

При нажатии на кнопку "Next page" браузер меняет ссылку, но содержимое не меняет.

**Я не могу понять как поменять содержимое?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поменять можно вручную, с помощи javascript, ajax, и т.д. Чтобы перейти на другую страницу, нужно `window.location.href = "/адрес/страницы";`. Функция `history.push()` говорит браузеру, что нужно сделать видимость перехода на другую страницу (смена адреса в адресной строке), а страницу сгенерирует код внутри страницы. На этом принципе построен vk, это позволяет экономить трафик и прослушивать музыку при переходе на другую страницу.

Comment: Но если мы меняем страницу с помощью `window.location.href = "/адрес/страницы";` то уже не сохраняется ссылка которую мы задали `history.pushState ("bar.html", "Страница #2", "/bar.html");`

Comment: @ProstoJohn я дописал, посмотри.

Comment: А можно пример? Просто не могу понять как сформулировать код ;(

Comment: @ProstoJohn Знаешь, как изменять содержимое страницы с помощью js?

Comment: Типо innerHTML?

Comment: @ProstoJohn да. Так вот, изменяешь содержимое страницы, затем пишешь history.pushState().

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35049/discussion-between---and-prostojohn).